# Rails 3 getting nested records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My setup: Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.9.2

Models:

```
class User
 has_many :posts
 has_many :photos

class Post
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :comments

class Photo
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :comments

class Comment
 belongs_to :post
 belongs_to :photo
```

At the `User` level, I would like to grab all the comments attached to `user.posts` and `user.photos`, is that possible and if so, what's the syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`user.posts.map(&:comments)` or `user.photos.map(&:comments)`

Comment: You rock, my man. In Ruby, it's almost always that 1 line of code that I need to figure out. What does the `&` do?

Comment: And an added bonus question, what if I need to pass a `where` value to `comments` like date to only return records > a certain date?

Comment: something like `user.posts.map { |p| p.comments.where(:date < 10.days.ago) }` or something along those lines